# WPF Simple table layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm looking to create a simple layout for a WPF project I'm working on. [image: Table layout]

I tried styling Datagrid and GridView's but none of them work as I want, plus I don't want items to be editable / selectable, or columns to be sorted or anything like that. Basically I just want a simple dynamic table layout with no bells and whistles.

Any advice on how to recreate this would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I need the number of rows to be dynamic based on an ObservableCollection

Comment: Blend may help you. Make a grid with two rows and columns and place two stack panels for Document Name and Actions accordingly.

Comment: Add ListView to the GridView for the column formatting

Answer (score 4):

Use HeaderedItemsControl, XAML

```
    <!-- templates -->

    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemWithDeleteButton">
        <Grid Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DocumentName, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}" x:Key="DeletedGrid">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>                              
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Document Name" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Actions"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="White">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    <!-- control -->

    <HeaderedItemsControl Style="{StaticResource DeletedGrid}" Margin="0,0,0,10" 
                                  Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemWithDeleteButton}"                                      
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}">
```

ViewModel

```
    public class GridItem
    {
      public string DocumentName { get; set; }
      public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
      public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridData { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just something similar.  For the second column you would probably use a button for Delete of maybe just click event on a TextBlock.   To get that exact formatting is going to take some tweaking.

```
<ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" x:Name="gvCurDocFields">
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Field" />   
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Path=FieldDefApplied.FieldDef.DispName, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Value" />
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Path=DispValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Grid layout for this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32" /> <!-- Header row -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- One for each row of data -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- Document Name column -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" /> <!-- Actions column -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can put a for example Listbox in the grid and bind it. The Grid is only for the Look part